# Access vba wrapper class handling events

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm try to write a wrapper class for getting events. This is a not working (EDIT: not show the message box) simple example: Where is the mistake?

```
' CLASSE1
Private WithEvents frm As Access.Form
Private Const Evented As String = "[Event Procedure]"
Public Sub Init(pFrm As Access.Form)
    Set frm = pFrm
    frm.OnLoad = Evented
End Sub
Private Sub frm_Load()
    MsgBox "OK!" 'NOT SHOW
End Sub

'Form1
Private SL As Classe1
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set SL = New Classe1
    SL.Init Me
End Sub
```

Comment: the "OK" message is not displayed

Comment: The form's `Load()` event has already been raised. Try a different event for testing.

Comment: I am attempting code. I put the CLASSE1 code in general module and immediately show a compile error on `Private WithEvents frm As Access.Form`. This must be in form module. If I put all code behind form then `Private SL As Classe1` errors because it is not in header. If I move it to header get error "User-defined type not defined".

Comment: @June7 I have a Class Module "Classe1" and a Fom module

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up the form load. This works:

**Class1**:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents frm As Access.Form
Private Const Evented As String = "[Event Procedure]"

Public Sub Initialize(pFrm As Access.Form)
    Set frm = pFrm
    frm.OnCurrent = Evented
End Sub

Public Sub Terminate()
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub frm_Current()
    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

**Form1**:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private FormCollection   As Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim EventProcedure  As Class1
    
    Set EventProcedure = New Class1
    Set FormCollection = New Collection

    EventProcedure.Initialize Me.Form
    FormCollection.Add EventProcedure, Me.Name

    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

    ' Unload events for all colour value textboxes.
    
    Dim EventProcedure  As Class1
    
    For Each EventProcedure In FormCollection
        EventProcedure.Terminate
    Next
    
    Set EventProcedure = Nothing
    Set FormCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Spelling out Init is not needed. @KostasK. comments have cause and correction.

Comment: I've cut down the code from an example of mine: [VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme).

Comment: That avoids the entire problem, namely, you're adding an event for `current`, not for `load`, and the problem is that the class is initialized on load so it's too late to hook into the `load` event.